# How to include an arbitrary kernel header file in a module?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

**Situation**

I'm writing a kernel module for learning purpose and want to use `sched_class_highest` and `for_each_class` as defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/kernel/sched/sched.h#L1172).

I saw that if I want to use symbols in the file /include/linux/sched.h, I'll `#include <linux/sched.h>`. So in the same manner, since the file I'm trying to add now is at location `/kernel/sched/sched.h`, I tried to: `#include`:

- First try: `<kernel/sched.h>`
- Second try: `<kernel/sched/sched.h>`
- Third try: `<../kernel/sched/sched.h>` - just copying paste from a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012742/how-to-include-math-h-include-math-h-on-kernel-source-file)

None of these worked and all gave me the error *No such file or directory*.

I'm not very familiar with C, just trying to learn the kernel and pick up C as I go a long the way.

Here's my Makefile. I knew basics about Makefile's target but don't understand the compiling process or what files it needs to feed it...

```
MODULE_FILENAME=my-schedule

obj-m +=  $(MODULE_FILENAME).o
KO_FILE=$(MODULE_FILENAME).ko

export KROOT=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

modules:
        @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
        @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean: 
        @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) clean
        rm -rf   Module.symvers modules.order

insert: modules
        sudo insmod $(KO_FILE)
        sudo dmesg -c

remove:
        sudo rmmod $(MODULE_FILENAME)
        sudo dmesg -c

printlog:
        sudo dmesg -c 
        sudo insmod $(KO_FILE)
        dmesg
```

**Questions**

1. How do I reference those 2 symbols in my kernel module?
2. Are those symbols supposed to be referenced directly by a *standard module*? If so, what is the standard way of doing it?
3. Is the Makefile related to how I can import a file in kernel code into my module?

Comment: you should mention you need linux module, not bsd one

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин it's tagged linux-kernel for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I reference those 2 symbols in my kernel module?

You should not need those in a "normal" kernel module. If you really do, re-define them in your module.

> Are those symbols supposed to be referenced directly by a standard module?

They are not, that particular `sched.h` file is only supposed to be used by scheduler code (files in `kernel/sched`). That's why it is not exported (i.e. not in the `include` dir). You will not find them in your headers folder (`/lib/modules/.../build`).

> Is the Makefile related to how I can import a file in kernel code into my module?

Unsure what this means really... if you want to know if there is some way to configure your Makefile such that it will be possible to include that file, then there is not. If you are building using the kernel headers exported by the kernel in `/lib/modules` (which is what you are doing when you hand over control to the kernel's Makefile with `$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT)`) then the file is simply not there.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me with follow up questions: 1) I'm not sure what you mean by redefine them. Are you suggesting I provide the logic for those functions by myself? I really don't want to do that because I'm looking at what the kernel has to offer. Essentially, I want to look into each sched class and see its list of tasks. However, I'm interested in how one might rewrite the `for_each_class` such that it provides the same capability as the kernel's version. 2) What kernel code files can I directly include in my module then? Is it just limited to those in the /include directory?

Comment: 3) `Unsure what this means really... if you want to know if there is some way to configure your Makefile...` I want to know if there are anyways at all to write a Makefile that allows me to include those files.

Comment: 1) redefine as in: directly copy-paste them into your module, that's how you would "rewrite" those 2) you can only include those that are under `include` directories 3) no there is no way, as I said the file is simply not there. The kernel does not export it to be used by modules.

Comment: 4) You said `include` directories - are there other `include` directories besides `/include` - ex: Could there be one at `/<n-level-of-other-directories>/include/`? And if there are, what is the path expected in the `#include <path>`?

Comment: There are a lot of them, a classic example is `/arch/<SOMEARCH>/include`, which are `include` dirs with architecture specific header files. Nonetheless, all the files in those are available to `#include` directly because the kernel Makefile specifically tells the compiler to look in all those directories by using the `-I<path>` option, so you usually don't have to worry about it.

Comment: `all the files in those are available to #include directly... so you usually don't have to worry about it.` -> so the file `/arch/alpha/include/asm/a.out.h` can be included in my module as `#include <asm/a.out.h>`?

Comment: @TranTriet Yep, exactly. [Here's an example](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/drivers/atm/idt77252.c#L47). Of course, for files under `arch` you will only be able to `#include` those that match the architecture you are compiling for.